# JavaScript "this" pointer in nested-functions

Tags: javascript, function, pointers, this

Here is a bit of non-working JavaScript code:

```
function clientEventsManager(io) {
    this.connectedClients = 0;

    this.createEventReceivers = function(io) {
        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
                this.connectedClients++;
                //does not increase "connectedClients" of "clientEventsManager" function
        }
    }

    createEventReceivers(io); //it is the only call to createEventReceivers()
}



var Manager = new clientEventsManager(io); //it is the only instanciation of clientEventsManager
```

My question is:
 Is there a way to change clientEventsManager.connectedClients in clientEventsManager.createEventReceivers()?

EDIT: this post is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), thank's for answering

Comment: You should be able to just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa277/. How are you calling the `fct1` method? The code is kind of "confusing" because `base` isn't capitalized (to signify a constructor). Are you just calling `base`, or are you constructing a new `base` and calling that instance's `fct1` method??

Comment: *"Is there a way to get the `attr1` attribute of base function in `base.fct1` function?"* Yes, many (well, maybe 4). Learn how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thanks for updating. I already assumed that it will be a **duplicate** of [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) (can't vote anymore though)

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you're putting the `createEventReceivers` function directly on the object in the constructor instead of on `clientEventManager.prototype`.

Comment: I did that because the Manager will be instanciated only once. Knowing that, I thought putting it directly in the constructor was better for reading and for best code folding... am I wrong to do that?

Comment: If there'll only be a single `Manager` instance, then a constructor function isn't really needed at all... or at least you could do it without adding a name to the variable scope. The simplest solution would be just to use an object literal, and have the callback reference that resulting object. There are other approaches as well. There are other approaches too.

Comment: [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg3m8/) using an object literal. And [here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg3m8/1/) using what's usually called a module pattern.

Comment: Please look at my edit - an important line I forgot. The function clientEventsManager.createEventReceiver() is in fact called when new clientEventsManager is invoked... does it change anything?

Comment: Given your current code, you'd need `this.` before the function call. I don't know which parts of the code are meant to be used once, and which parts are used multiple times, so I don't know the overall best approach.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution

```
function base(param) {
    this.attr1 = "azertyuiop";
    this.attr2 = 123;
    this.attr3 = param;
    var self=this;
    this.fct1 = function() {
        console.log("azerty keyboard first row: "+self.attr1);
        //Doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What problem is it solving?

Comment: getting the value of attr1, which isn't working. Just read the question before downvoting, you'll save a ton of clicks.

Comment: @amenadiel: Why is it not working?

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it's not very good. There's no problem given in the question, and so this as a "solution" is odd. We have no idea if the function should keep a permanently bound reference to `this`. Nor do we know what the value of `this` actually is.

Comment: @user3753446: You might not be able to do that, but what you certainly can is **clarify your question** and provide a **complete** example.

Comment: 1.- Because OP said so and I don't see a reason to judge him a liar, even if he's a confessed french. And 2.- Because the example might not be the exact situation OP is seeing, and whatever it is, I believe it's more helpful to store a reference to ```this``` in an auxiliary variable instead of reccomending the user to study variable scopes in JS.

Comment: @amenadiel: FWIW, no one suggested the OP to learn about variable scope (but it's still a good thing to know).

Comment: @amenadiel: He didn't say it doesn't work. Far as we know, he never tried it. Also, if `this` is the global object, then he's doing far more wrong. Finally, sometimes the solution is to permanently bind  the `this` value, sometimes not.

Comment: @amenadiel: Then you don't know the difference between `this` and scope in JS.

Comment: @amenadiel: I said to learn about `this`, which has nothing to do with variable scope. If one wants to use `this`, they should know how it works, shouldn't they?

Comment: You mean ```this``` doesn't have a scope that can change depending of the context?

Comment: @MagixKiller: It all depends on the actual problem. It's rare to create separate functions on `this` in a constructor *(if indeed your function is used as a constructor)*. More often you'd use prototypal inheritance. JavaScript is very flexible, and there are often multiple solutions to a problem. But the overall nature of the problem is important to know.

Comment: `this` is an implicitly defined local "variable" in every function, just like `arguments`. Of course `this` has scope, it's local to every function, but I would argue that the "problems" that arise with `this` don't actually have anything to with scope. All you need to know about scope with regard to `this` is that inner variables with the same name shadow outer variables.

Comment: Anyways, we digress. While your answer may "work", since we don't know how the code is actually used, what `this` actually refers to, inside `base` and inside `fct1`, you answer is just an (educated) guess.

Comment: See the OP edition. In fact, his example wasn't accurate. But I gave him a quick and dirty solution to solve those cases in which you need to address the class instance ```this``` from a callback, closure, method, etc. I know this is not teaching a man how to fish, but I don't aspire to do that.

Comment: @amenadiel: Then you can vote to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback